# Add 2 on last octet in IP-Address

Tags: excel, addition, ip-address, vba

I use following code to retreive IP-Addresses from one sheet to another.

```
  For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
  FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
  If IsNumeric(FR) Then c.Offset(, 13).Value = w2.Range("N" & FR).Value
  Next c
```

Is it possible to add 2 (+2) to the last octet at the same time?

Eg. 192.168.0.1 will be 192.168.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach (which assumes the values between the dots are numeric and that there are four elements, so might need some error trapping).

```
For Each c In w1.Range("D2", w1.Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    FR = Application.Match(c, w2.Columns("A"), 0)
    If IsNumeric(FR) Then
        v = Split(w2.Range("N" & FR).Value, ".")
        v(3) = v(3) + 2
        c.Offset(, 13).Value = Join(v, ".")
    End If
Next c
```

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. Unfortunately it doesn´t seems to do anything.
I still get the same IP Address as in the other sheet.

Comment: Worked when I tested it with a single cell. Have you stepped through the code to check what is happening?

Comment: My bad, I was looking in wrong column. It works as intended. Thanks for your support!